# mysqld_safe Fatal error: Can't remove the pid file

Tags: mysql, pid

Getting this error when trying to run the command /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe:

```
    mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Users-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
    cat: /usr/local/mysql/data/Users-MacBook-Pro.local.pid: Permission denied
    rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/mysql/data/Users-MacBook-Pro.local.pid’: 
    Permission   denied
    140313 11:09:18 mysqld_safe Fatal error: Can't remove the pid file:
    /usr/local/mysql/data/Users-MacBook-Pro.local.pid
    Please remove it manually and start /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe again;
    mysqld daemon not started
    /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 129: 
    /usr/local/mysql/data/Users-MacBook-   Pro.local.err: Permission denied
```

Shoould I remove the file? Is it safe to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this pid file, make sure all the instances are stopped (kill any processes not going down), check nothing is listening the MySQL port 3306 (netstat should help) and try to start MySQL again.

To troubleshoot this see the permission you user has on the folder where the pid needs to be stored !

Comment: removed the pid file as a super user, however still getting an error: 140313 12:25:37 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Users-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
140313 12:25:37 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 129: /usr/local/mysql/data/Users-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/mysql.sock’: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: /usr/local/mysql/data/Users-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied

Comment: run a "ps -ef | grep mysql" and kill all results

Comment: what is this ? the output !

Comment: can you list the permission for the /usr/local/mysql/data ! does your user has full rights on that path ?

Comment: yes the output after deleting .pid file. Sorry for such a mess output, couldn't format it nicely in the comment.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 11 _mysql wheel   374 Mar 13 12:18 data

Comment: try to create file inside that folder and remove it - just to check ! you have rights

Comment: Permission denied to create a file

Comment: so thats it ! fix this - from the terminal run 'chown user:group /usr/local/mysql/data'

Comment: even when I change the permission of data directory from _mysql to root, still says permission denied to run /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe

Comment: ok so , find a folder where you have write access, and the alter you my.cnf file and edit the data-dir variable pointing to that place! got it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command with SUDO in front of it, like this

sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe

Enter your password. This will most likely resolve your problem.

The reason you are getting these errors is because the command you are running to start mysql requires access to certain files (listed in the error message). You need root access to these files to start mysql, so by adding sudo to the start of the command, you are giving root access.